# Mixed Effects Model with M-values and Phenotype data in lme4

Tags: lme4, mixed-models, illumina

I am relatively new to R and am having an issue with lme4. I want to use my methylation (m-values) and my phenotypic datasets. However, when I run my code I get an error about different variable lengths. I believe I need to combine these datasets into one, but I am so lost at how to do this and could really use some help.

Original lme4 code:

binTP.lme= lmer(adj.m ~ pheno$condition + pheno$Sex + pheno$Age.at.collection + pheno$smoke + pheno$EUR + pheno$AFR + (1|pheno$pairing))

Error message: Error in model.frame.default(drop.unused.levels = TRUE, formula = adj.m ~ : variable lengths differ (found for 'pheno$condition')

adj.m dimensions = 586229 46
pheno dimensions = 46 15

Thanks in advance!